# Python dictionary's order

Tags: python

As I know, python dictionary is an unordered datastructure. But when it comes to that I insert a key-value pairs into dictionary and traverse it. Surprisedly find it outputs each orderedly.Why ? Use python3.6 .

Comment: Coincidence. The order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Happy accident. Don't rely on it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Not true in Python 3.6

Comment: It is *not* an accident in Python 3.6 (at least, not when using the CPython interpreter).